# MySql MySqlDataReader Documentation?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to use MySql inside of a C# application - so far, I am having mixed results.

I can connect and issue the commands just fine, however, I am having real issues processing the output and results.

I can't seem to find firm and good documentation. The only official documentation I can seem to find is here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html

My biggest problem is that I just can't understand the basics...

```
while (Reader.Read())
```

The documentation just doesn't really go in to any details on how this works.

After I have done the above, I have seen a few different examples, and I can pull the data in the following ways

```
Console.WriteLine(Reader[0] + " - " + Reader[1]);
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",");
```

However, I can't seem to find documentation that covers either and do not fully understand what is happening.

At the moment, I do not want specific code examples, I would just ideally like a link to some solid and good documentation or (/preferably in addition) an explanation on what Reader.Read is doing and the two other code examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can read the documentation of the [.NET IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) and it's pretty much all you need to start.

you use code like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(Reader[0] + " - " + Reader[1]);
```

if you already know that what you need is in the first and second column of the query and you use the `for loop` approach if you want to show / use all columns without knowing how many columns you get from the query. Usually in a real world application you write queries and stored procedure which select only some fields (not use `SELECT *...`) so you know exactly the position of which columns you are dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

> The documentation just doesn't really go in to any details on how this works.

Beginner hint:

A  DataReader implemtents IDataReader which is fully documented in the .NET farmework.

> while (Reader.Read())

Reads the next line, returning true if that was possible,false if not (end of data).

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answers in the more general [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what problem you are having.  The while(Reader.Read()) code is just running a loop as as long as there is another record to read in your Reader object.  The documentation site that you list gives everything you need to know.  What do you really think is missing?

Have you looked at Visual Studio help in regards to DataReaders and how they work?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a MySql Connector Help file, .chm file, that is installed as part of the installation for the [MySql .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), if the option is selected which is by default selected.

On my workstation running Windows 7 64 Bit, with the MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4 installed, the help file is located in the following directory, there should also be a Start Menu Item unser "MySql" -> "MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4".

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4\Documentation
```

As for samples you can pretty much use any of the IDataReader examples and replace the IDataReader with the MySqlDatareader.